# Using An Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an assignment in which I have to Write a function named "addEmUp" declared this way:

```
function addEmUp() {

     // Your code goes here.

};
```

addEmUp returns the total of the numbers in an array. The name of the array is LASVEGAS and the array has 3 values in it.

The array LASVEGAS exists - do not create it - just use it.

I am clueless, how do I write this function?

Thanks

Comment: If you've made the decision that you don't want to learn to do your own homework, you should at least learn how to use google.

Comment: Check out [these tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) for the usage of arrays

Comment: Try to code yourself and post the issue here. Don't expect anyone to do the homework for you. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+tutorial+array&aq=0&oq=javascript+tutorial+array&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 check this link for Javascript array concepts.

Comment: Hint: don't assume the array has three values in it, use the array's `length` property (`LASVEGAS.length`) - that way your code will work on arrays with any number of items in them.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
var sum = LASVEGAS.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;});
```

Now go find out yourself how to implement this in your function.

Comment: I just wondered myself whether to recommend [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for sums to a newbie :)

Comment: @Bergi - It's perfect: It will be obvious to his teacher that he used the internet to do his homework.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and iterate over each item in the array.

You might want to use a variable to keep track of a running total.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer because I just wanted to make understand things. I am not doing your homework, that is what you are supposed to do.

Now, LASVEGAS is an array with 3 values.. Don't stick to 3 values, I can be any of any length.

Let us assume a generic array example

```
 LASVEGAS = [1,5,"a","b", true, false, , 34];
```

Next your requirement is to extract length of numbers exists in an array. You have to use filter the array using `filter` function. But this will not work in old browsers. If you are targetting only modern browsers then below code should work

```
 LASVEGAS.filter(function(e) { return typeof e == "Number"; } )    
 // It will return filtered array of Numbers
```

So, if you are targetting old browsers also, then add the below code somewhere in your page.

```
 /**
  * Copyright (c) Mozilla Foundation http://www.mozilla.org/
  * This code is available under the terms of the MIT License
 */
 if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
 Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this)) {
                res.push(val);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
  };
 }
```

And if you want to work on exact on exact requirement and if don't need any generic way below code also will do the work

```
 LASVEGAS.Numbers = 0;
 for(var i = 0, j = LASVEGAS.length; i < j ; i++){
    if(typeof LASVEGAS[i] == "Number") LASVEGAS.Numbers;  
 }
```

And next time, dont post these types of Questions. We are not here to do your Home work.

Comment: Those uses of `.filter()` don't do remotely what your corresponding comments say. (`LASVEGAS.filter(Boolean)`, for example, would keep every value except `false` since all the other values are "truthy" - see http://jsfiddle.net/2dgXf/) What do you even mean by "clean the array"? Your code `LASVEGAS.filter(function(e){ return e; });` will also just return all the "truthy" elements...

Comment: @nnnnnn I mean clean an array with removing undefined elements or null elements. And please check the edited answer.